# Pages redirect me to the homepage

Tags: multisite, pages, admin, wp-admin, redirect

I am the admin of a multi Wordpress websites that are controlled from one Administration page.

After updating to the latest version of Wordpress, 3.6.1, all of the pages are redirected to the to the homepage.

Does anybody experienced this problem before?

Thanks in advance

Comment: disable plugins, switch to default theme, see if issue persists. also maybe flush the rewrite rules to regenerate the .htaccess file.

Comment: I disabled every plugin, and switched to the default. Yes it does persist

Comment: What do you mean by multiple sites being controlled by one admin page? Are you talking about multisite?

Answer (score 0):

Use phpMyAdmin then.

MAKE A BACKUP before you do this!

In the table wp_X_options (where X is that site's ID number), under the option_name column (field) find the active_plugins row.

Change the option_value field to: a:0:{}

Ref : [link](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wordpress-multisite-sub-sites-all-redirect-to-the-main-site)